# CodeIgniter class loading is not working

Tags: codeigniter, class, view

I have a class in application/library folder - filename = person_struc.php and the code is following..

```
class Person_struc {
    var $person_id;
    var $person_name;   

    public function set_info($person_id, $person_name) {
        $this->person_id = $person_id;
        $this->person_first_name = $person_name;
    }
}
```

I have a view (person_list.php) and want to load the class by as follows -

```
$this->load->library('person_struc');
$this->person_struc->set_info(1,"xxx");
```

I have controller (person) and model (person_model). But it is generating error..

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$person_struc

Filename: person/person_list.php

Fatal error: Call to a member function set_info() on a non-object in
```

I tried to solve the problem but failed. Do you have any solution please...

Comment: do you load library in view?

Answer (score 0):

Initial letter of your file name must be capital. In your case it would be filename = Person_struc.php instead of filename = person_struc.php

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
class Person_struc extends CI_Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

your class must be locate in library.
your class name and file name are same.
and your person_list controller must be extends CI_CONTROLLER